# Why does the program writes output like this?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

I wonder why is the output of this c++ program X:f1? Is there a call of y object, is it logical to call Y's f1()? Shouldn't there be an inheritance? I'm confused...

```
    class X {
    public:
        void f1() { cout<<"X:f1"<<endl;}
    };
    class Y : public X {
    public:
        void f1() { cout<<"Y:f1"<<endl;}
    };
    Y* y = new Y();
    void f(X* x) { x -> f1(); }
    int main () { f (y);
    system("pause");
    return 1;
    }
```

And how to change body of f() function and arguments it takes to get Y:f1 at the output?

Comment: Declare the function `f1()` as `virtual`

Comment: If you are coming from a language like Java, Python etc where all instance methods are virtual, then you should read about them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `X::f1` isn't `virtual`, calls to it are statically dispatched, i.e. in this case they are dispatched based on the static type of `x` (which is `X`) and not the dynamic type of it (which in this case is `Y`).

Put another way, because `X::f1` isn't `virtual`, the fact that `x` points to an instance of `Y` when you call `f(y)` isn't taken into consideration - the compiler dispatches all calls to `X::f1` to `X`'s `f1` regardless of the dynamic (i.e. run-time) type of the object pointed to by `x`.

Unlike in other languages (e.g. Java), member functions in C++ are not `virtual` by default - you have to explicitly specify that you want subclasses to be able to override them.

To get the output you expect, you need to add a `virtual` qualifier to `X::f1` - you can't sensibly achieve what you want by changing just the body of `f` as you suggest because you're discarding the information about `x`'s dynamic type, but you could change the arguments of `f` to accept a `Y*` rather than an `X*` in this particular case.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks a lot, i just forgot that 'tiny' detail :) Cheers!

Comment: @anicicn That's **certainly not** a _tiny detail_, but a very fundamental point in c++ programming!

Comment: Is it really answer to the question?

Comment: @Slava: I've added a bit to answer it more explicitly.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz I understand, but his question is specific - how to change function `f()`

Comment: @StuartGolodetz he did not insist of changing the body of `f()` without changing the signature, did you read the question? huh

Comment: @Slava: Yes, I did. That's why I said "if you were to insist on that". See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood. It turns out I made a mistake in any case though, so I've removed it.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz he says "how to change body of f() function and **arguments** it takes to get Y:f1 at the output?" where did you get "if he insists" part when he actually said exactly opposite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60580/discussion-between-stuart-golodetz-and-slava).

Comment: @Slava: I was attempting to provide additional value by saying that had he insisted on that (he didn't, quite evidently), it would have been possible (had X been a polymorphic type) to achieve what he wanted simply by changing the body of f and leaving the arguments alone. Had X been a polymorphic type, that had the potential to be an interesting aside that the OP might have found useful. As it happens, I missed the fact that X wasn't a polymorphic type, so I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 4):

You get this problem because the function isn't declared virtual. You need to add the `virtual` qualifier to `X`'s `f1` to allow subclasses to override it.

```
class X {
public:
    virtual void f1() { cout<<"X:f1"<<endl;}
};

class Y : public X {
public:
    virtual void f1() { cout<<"Y:f1"<<endl;}
};
```

If you don't, `Y`'s `f1` will be called only if the compiler is aware of the object's type. This is not the case when you convert it to an `X*`. This is the behavior that you observe:

```
Y* y = new Y;
y->f1(); // prints "Y:f1"
X* x = y;
x->f1(); // prints "X:f1"!
```

Answer (score 1):

> And how to change body of f() function and arguments it takes to get
>   Y:f1 at the output?

Actual answer to your question is:

```
void f(Y* y) { y -> f1(); }
```

Though there is no much sense of having non virtual method with the same name and signature in derived class, other than to produce difficult to catch problems.

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code in my compiler in this way

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class X {
public:
     virtual void f1() { cout<<"X:f1"<<endl;}
  // ^^^^^^^ Note my changes here!
};
class Y : public X {
public:
    void f1() { cout<<"Y:f1"<<endl;}
};

Y* y = new Y();
void f(X* x) { x -> f1(); }

int main () {
    f(y);
    return 1 ;
}
```

and the output is `Y:F1` not `X:F1` as u said try this again ,

Comment: this is not my code I posted. You inserted virtual which I don't have in the post above.

Comment: @omar-khaled Do better at the 1st shot next time!